# Javascript google addsence open in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have put google add sense code in my html page. But every time this link open in same tab. I want to open in new tab. I have googled for this and found following link.
 https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354740?hl=en.
 They are saying that they are not allow to open in new tab.But I have seen some sites like flipkart, amazon, w3school site in these site google add sence open in new tab. So the my question is there any way any one know please let us known.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Not getting any solution yet.

Comment: I am also facing same.. Any solutions ??

Answer (score -1):

add attrubute target "_blank" to your  tag

```
 <a href="site.html" target="_blank">some text</a>
```

Comment: Google provide javascript code. We just need to put javascript code in header section. We are not creating anchor tag. google automatically create it. Thanks for quick reply.